# Insertar datos de dos tablas diferentes en una nueva tabla postgresql

Tags: array, postgresql, function, insert, sql

lo que quiero hacer es insertar la información de las tabla curso y la tabla estudiante en una tabla nueva llamada curso_est, es decirque esta es una relación M a N, quiero que los estudiantes tengan asignados todos los cursos o que los cursos tengan muchos estudiantes,pero no sé como insertar esta información en la nueva.

```
Esta es la base de datos

    CREATE TABLE Cursos (
        cod_cur varchar(6),
        nomb_cur varchar(30),
        cod_doc varchar(10)
    );
    ALTER TABLE Cursos ADD CONSTRAINT rk_cursos PRIMARY KEY(cod_cur);
    CREATE TABLE Estudiantes (
        cod_est varchar(10),
        nomb_est varchar(30),
        telefono varchar(10),
        email varchar(50),
        cod_programa varchar(10)
    );
    ALTER TABLE Estudiantes ADD CONSTRAINT ek_estudiantes PRIMARY KEY(cod_est);
CREATE TABLE curso_est(
    cod_est varchar(10),
    cod_cur varchar(11)
);
ALTER TABLE curso_est ADD CONSTRAINT INSCRITO FOREING KEY (cod_cur) REFERENCES cursos(cod_cur) ON DELATE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
ALTER TABLE curso_est ADD CONSTRAINT INSCRITOS FOREING KEY (cod_est) REFERENCES estudiantes(cod_est) ON DELATE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

La tabla estudiante se ve así:

[image: Esta seria la tabla estudiante]

La tabla curso se ve así:

[image: Tabla curso]

Y la tabla curso_est quiero que se vea de la siguienta manera,pero no sé como hacer ese insert:

[image: tabla curso_est]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes mal escrita la definición de los constraints. En vez de

> FOREING KEY (cod_cur) REFERENCES cursos(cod_cur) ON DELATE -- etc etc

debe ser

> FOREI**GN** KEY (cod_cur) REFERENCES cursos(cod_cur) ON DEL**E**TE -- etc etc

Para insertar las combinaciones de ambas tablas bastaría con

```
insert into curso_est
select cod_est,cod_cur
from Cursos, Estudiantes;
```

Pero es más claro el propósito si lo escribes como

```
insert into curso_est
select cod_est,cod_cur
from Cursos CROSS JOIN Estudiantes;
```

Atento al comportamiento de poner `ON UPDATE NO ACTION` en vez de `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. En el improbable caso en que quieras actualizar el ID de un estudiante o de un curso, arrojará un error. Esto tiene su utilidad dependiendo del caso de uso, pero asegúrate de definir qué quieres que ocurra en ese escenario.

Ver en [<kbd>SQLFiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c0438/3)

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfectamente, te lo agradezco.